# How can specify limit for trace collection in OS X wireshark?

Tags: networking, macos, wireshark

Wireshark noob here, trying to figure out how to set a limit for trace collection in OS X Wireshark. I did a search on the wiki page but nothing comes up in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try poking around in the UI? On Wireshark 2.0.1 Mac, I have this:

`Capture > Options… > Options > Stop capture automatically after…`